In which Star Wars movie does Master Yoda say: “Fear is the path to the dark side....”?
In which Star Wars movie does Master Yoda say:

Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads
  to hate. Hate leads to suffering.

Here is the youtube scene:




You see kid anakin in the first second of the video. Is that not a dead giveaway?

No enough, man. Time's so valuable for me to ask for things I already know. @cairdcoinheringaahing

It is from Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace. This is the fourth movie ever released in the Star Wars series and comes first in the timeline of the entire series. 
Movie Script
This line of dialogue occurs when Anakin is first introduced to the Jedi Council in order to seek training as a Jedi.
